# Woher stammt der umgangssprachliche Ausdruck „Boah ey“?

Tags: etymology, slang, interjection

Woher kommt der umgangssprachliche Ausdruck „Boah ey“? Für mich sieht er sehr seltsam aus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Im [Wikipedia-Artikel über den Ausruf *"Ey!"*](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ey_%28Ausruf%29) steht, der Ausdruck sei als Teil der sogenannten Jugendsprache, restringierter Soziolekte/Ethnolekte aufgekommen und hätte als anerkennende Form weite Verbreitung im Rahmen der in den späten 1980er Jahren beliebten [Mantawitze](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mantawitz) gefunden.

Auch im [Diagramm von Googles Ngram Viewer](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=boah&year_start=1984&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=3) wird der Trend seit den achtziger Jahren angezeigt:

[image: Boah ey! Ngram]

Es könnte sein, dass sich der Ausruf aus dem Begriff [*"Bohei"*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Bohei) entwickelt hat. Er bedeutet "Aufheben" im Sinne von *Aufstand* und *Spektakel* und hat sich vielleicht aus dem Westmitteldeutschen und Rheinischen aus den Ausrufen *bu(h)* und *hei* gebildet oder aus dem Niederländischen (älter niederländisch boeha [heute: poeha] = Lärm, Tumult; Aufheben) gebildet.

Es gibt einige interessante Artikel und Diskussionen, die sich um den Ausruf *Bohei* drehen:

- http://blog.wissen.de/wissen/ressort/sprachspione/das-bohei-ums-buhei/
- http://blogs.taz.de/wortistik/2007/01/07/bohai/ ([archiviert](https://web.archive.org/web/20220119204106/http://blogs.taz.de/wortistik/2007/01/07/bohai/))

Answer (score 4):

Laut Duden hat [boah](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/boah) eine lautmalende Herkunft und [ey](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ey) kommt aus dem Englischen (ich vermute von [hey](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hey)).

Spaßeshalber habe ich mal das Google Groups Archiv durchkämmt, dort kommt der Begriff das erste Mal im Jahr 1990 in einer [Liste](http://groups.google.com/group/sub.jokes/browse_thread/thread/987e695d3ff3a08c/67fe01620815457e) von [Mantawitzen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mantawitz) vor.

Comment: Zu "boah" vgl. auch "woah": http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=woah

Answer (score -4):

Der Ausruf

> Boah ey!

hat seine Quelle in der Zoologie. Dem Vernehmen nach stammt der Spruch aus Frankfurt. Der Frankfurter Zoo hatte einst in seinem Bestand eine phänomenal große Boa Constrictor. Zoobesucher vor dem Schlangengehege wurden regelmäßig dabei beobachtet, wie sie mit offenem Mund die Riesenschlange anstarrten und verblüfft ihren Namen riefen ("Boa!"). Von dort nahm die Tradition bei Zoomitarbeitern ihren Ausgang, angesichts großer, erstaunlicher oder überraschender Dinge scherzhaft "Boa ey" zu sagen. Das angehängte h verdeutlicht nur die Länge des Vokals.

Comment: Ich hab mal eben auf den Kalender geguckt - aber heute ist doch gar nicht der 32. März???

Comment: Also wenn schon, dann *Seeschlange* statt Boa. Sonst passt's nicht zu Manta.

Comment: +1 für diesen Beitrag. In satira veritas!

Answer (score -4):

Bereits althochdeutsch **bor, por** "Höhe, Spitze" wird adverbial wie "sehr" gebraucht<sup>[*]</sup> und lebt bspw. in *empor ragen* weiter. Die Interjektion *Boah!* ist zwar kein Adverb im eigentlichen Sinn kann aber typischer Weise satzadverbial gebraucht werden. Übrigens ist "boah ey" erst für die Achtziger Jahre online nachweisbar, doch sicherlich älter.

*) *bora-* verstärkende Partikel, nur in Zusammensetzungen. S.d. z.B. *bora-reht, borreht* "vollauf berechtigt, hinlänglich" (Etymologisches Wörterbuch des Althochdeutschen)

---

1. Bor

Lautlich ist *boah* in Gebieten mit Tiefschwa'igem *-r* kaum von *bor* zu unterscheiden. Tatsächlich wird der Ausruf häufig genauso buchstabiert, ist ohne den Zusatz "ey" aber nicht so leicht aufzuspüren (ich meine das auf r/de gesehen zu haben).

Demgegenüber sind auch guterale wie frikative Anklänge zu vernehmen, etwa /bɔχ/, oft wie *och* /ɔχ/, engl. *oh man* ("och menno"). "Das angehängte h verdeutlicht nur die Länge des Vokals", wie @ChristianGeiselman (oben) schon sagt. Eine genauere phonologische Untersuchung ist mir nicht gegeben.

Pfeifer erklärt *empor* so:

> "althochdeutsch *in bor(e)* ‘in die Höhe’"

> "*bor(e)*, Akkusativ bzw. Dativ von ahd. *bor* ‘Höhe, Spitze’" (DWDS: *empor*)

Das *-e* genügt zwar nicht, um direkten Anschluss an *ey* herzustellen (sowieso bleibt hypothetisch unbegründet, ob *ey* ein altes Pronomen fortsetzt, s. urindoeuropäisch *ey ~ *ís, *yós-)

Während Bichlmeyer *et al.* von *bher- "tragen" im Anlaut ausgehen*, wäre besser ein Präfix anzunehmen, was mit *empor* vergleichbar sein sollte, falls Assimilation und Apocope in *bor* wahrscheinlich ist. Dann könnte *-b-* reine Epenthese (etwa *Empfang*), Prothese (etwa *bwahaha*) oder Kasusendung sein (bspw lat. *ubi ubi* "überall"). Vgl. dementsprechend *mehr*, *immer*, sowie älter *michel* "groß". Ist der Ablaut etwa keltisch oder slavisch (s. urie. *mogh-)?

Dafür sollte man am besten weiter auf urindogermanisch **HreG- gehen, vgl. ferner *reich, recht, magnus rex, rulez0r* usw., jedoch unsicher laut Pfeifer *regen, empor ragen* mit altenglisch
*oferhrǣgan* "sich emportürmen"—*ich bin empört* und *erregt* zugleich. *Ohrfeigen* mit Haplologie. Damit wird der Ausruf *boah ey* um einiges schwieriger zu ergründen. Die altenglische Form sieht allerdings wie Reduplikation aus, nur ist fortis g in der Regel unerwarten

In Sätzen sieht das Mittelhochdeutsch bei Bennecke (BMZ) z.B. so aus:

> **α.** *in bejahenden sätzen.* ir sît einander enbor holt *seid sehr gute freunde Reinh. f. 1654.*

> er fröwete sich enbore vil daʒ er ein schâf vunden hete *Leyser pred. 63,30*.

> dô si stuont enbor lange *(borlange?)* mit sorgen bevangen, zuo disem sêre wart ir nôt mêre *Tundal. 54,80.*

Vergleich demgegenüber moderne Wendungen, i. *Ihr seid mir vielleicht ein paar*, *ein paar tolle Freunde* (vgl. [ein paar Mal](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/31606/warum-ist-das-mal-in-ein-paar-mal-singular?r=SearchResults&s=8%7C61.9120)) ii. *er freut sich en Kullerkeks*, iii. *sie war empört* (auch *disem sêre*, vgl. *unversehrt*, heute aber *diese Misere*). Von Originaltreue kann nicht die Rede sein.

Beispiele mit negation sind schon früh undurchsichtig, "*in verneinenden sätzen.* daʒ mir êr bore unchunt ne was *nicht gänzlich unbekannt* N. Boeth. 183."

Nur in den Beispielen, in denen es alleine steht, tritt eine Bedeutung von Höhe noch hervor. Ob das überhaupt die selben Worte sind, ist nicht offensichtlich.

---

2. Bohei

Wegen Lautmalerei dürfte das ganzer Zufall sein. Siehe so zufällig engl. *emperor*, *ambassador*, tschech. *boh* "Gott", griech. *basileus* "Herschet", *amphora* (*phero* "bringen" tatsäcich verwandt). An Ausrufen s. a. engl. *aye* (aus Nordisch, wohl verwandt mit intensiven *je-* bzw. regional *ie-, e-*, s. oberfränkisch *etzala* "jetzt", englisch *for ever* "für immer", *e'ry day* "alltäglich"), ohne Kommentar: *wow*, *woah*, *oi oi oi* wie *heu heu heu*.

Allerdings hat der Ausruf oft negativen Charakter, *boah (ne) ey* (ebenso BMZ, *bor*: "enbor chunt ne was").

Siehe dafür engl. *boring* (was wie ich annehme mit *bor* verwandt), *bah, humbug*, ita. *basta*? *Das ist ja wohl der Gipfel (der Frechheit)*, ebenso *~ die Höhe, die Spitze, der Hammer* ... *Kein Bock, ey* ... Ein gut widersinniges Paar wie *awesome / awful* scheint möglich.

Der angeführte Vergleich mit "Bohei" (s. o. @splattne) ist bemerkenswert. Doch sicherlich führt *bua* + *hei* (?) vorerst genauso auf lautmalerei, was hier ungefähr bedeuten kann, dass der Ausruf zur Zeit der niederschrift kaum noch verständlich war, falls das überhaupt belegbar ist. S. auch *hoch*, engl. *high*. Die üblichen Quellen führen für *Buhei, Bohei* keine Etymologie (Kluge, DWDS; Duden ist unbeachtlich). Siehe dafür niederländisch *poeha* (etymologiebank.nl; Übersetzung und Hervorhebung von mir):

> "[...] with numerous by-forms such as *boeha* {1578} *bohaai, behaai* [...], probably formed from *boo!* + *ha!*" (PAF van Veen and N. van der Sijs (1997))

Natürlich, Wald und Wiesen Onotomatopoeia gehen immer. Andererseits ist eine Quellenangabe für so eine sinnige Hypothese mangels Schöpfungshöhe offensichtlich unnötig gewesen. Phillipa *et al.* behandeln das Wort gleich gar nicht. Aber warte mal:

> "[...] also *boeha , poohaai* , cf. in [Plantijn] *bohay*; written with p since the 18th century. The word is very reminiscent of fra. *brouhaha*, **which is not a pure sound word** but since the 17th century the name for the shouting of the devil-dressed clergy in mystery plays, to be derived from hebr. *bārūkh hab-ba* [...]. It would not be impossible that the nnl. word originated from medieval drama." (J. de Vries (1971))

Der Vergleich ist begründet, *brouhaha* ist aber nicht offensichtlich Hebräisch. Siehe etwa die zahlreichen varianten unter fr. *brag-* "schreien", vgl. englisch *brag*, ferner deutsch *brüllen, plärren*, allesamt unsicher (etymonline, DWDS), außerdem *bellen* (das seinerseits auch nicht vom Belzebub stammt).

TLFi stützt die Aussage mit weiteren Verweisen:

> [*1. 1548*] Le curé, habillé en dyable : **Brou, brou, brou, ha, ha, Brou, ha, ha.**

> [*2. 1552*] subst. (Ch. ESTIENNE, Dictionarium latinogallicum, s.v. tragoedias agere : faire d'ung neant une grande chose, faire ung grand **brouhaha** pour un rien)

D.h. *ein großes **Buhei** um nichts machen*, bzw. auch *Aufheben(s)* in demselben Sinne, so *embor* "heben" (BMZ).

> Orig. discutée. L'hyp. la plus probable semble être celle d'une altération onomatopéique de l'hébr.

> ces paroles, fréquemment empl. dans les prières juives, auraient été déformées par ceux qui ignorent l'hébreu.

Demnach ist hebr. *barukh habba [beshem adonai]* Psalm 118:26 (bei Luther: "Gelobt sei, der da kommt [im Namen des HERRN!]") in Passionsspielen üblich gewesen und von unwissenden korrumpiert worden bis hin zu « *Hho, hho, hho, hho, brrrourrrourrrs, rrrourrrs, rrrourrrs. Hou, hou, hou. Hho, hho, hho. Frere Estienne, faisons nous pas bien les Diables?* » (cf. [TLFi](http://stella.atilf.fr/Dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/advanced.exe?8;s=1721357610;)), was im Spiel durchaus erschreckend komisch sein dürfte.

Tatsächlich soll selbst die Bibelstelle den Gesang einer Prozession wiedergeben ([Kommentare](https://biblehub.com/commentaries/psalms/118-26.htm))

> "These words of welcome are probably spoken by the Levite in charge, to the procession approaching the gates. According to Rabbinical writings, pilgrim caravans were thus welcomed on their arrival at Jerusalem." (Ellicott)

Jamiet-Focet Brown (ebenda) weiß darüber: "typically it belongs to Him of whom the phrase became an epithet (Mal 3:1; Mt 21:9).", womit wohl der Judenkönig im christlichen Kontext gemeint sein dürfte (ebenda, Cambridge Bible for Schools and Colleges): "With these words and with the Hosanna[77] (‘save now’) of the preceding verse, the multitudes greeted Jesus as He rode into Jerusalem (Matthew 21:9). The Psalm may already have received a Messianic interpretation."

Dass daraus *Bohei* und ebenfalls *boah ey* hervorgehen würde ist nunmehr reine Spekulation. Die Wortgruppe ist längst nicht nur West-Rheinisch doch früher nicht belegt. Van Veen und van der Sijs, denen de Vries wohl bekannt sein dürfte, nehmen die Hypothese nicht an, eröffnen aber auch keinen stichhaltigen Gegenbeweis.

*Bor, por* ist zumindest dialektal und auch schon Mittelhochdeutsch belegt, und zwar reichlich (cf. [Woerterbuchnetz](https://woerterbuchnetz.de/?sigle=Lexer&lemid=L00060#1)), so z.B. schweizer deutsch *Krǖzbār* "Prozession mit Kreuzen", *Gebarr* "Lärm" (Idiotikon), ebenso mittelhochdeutsch *bôr* "trotz, empörung" (BMZ). Außerdem sagen manche heutzutage *ahnbar* (Money Boy, passim; welcher auch mit althochdeutschem Einschlag vongsprachlich *i bims* zu vertreten hat). Siehe übrigens neuerdings auch jugendsprachlich *porno, das ist so porno*.

Genauso könnte man *berüchtigt* dahinstellen, "das auf mnd. *berüchtigen* ‘Geschrei erheben, in guten oder schlechten Ruf bringen’ (vgl. auch gleichbed. mnd. *berüchten*) beruht" und sofern mit "Ruf" verwand doch einer indogermanischen Etymologie entbehrt (DWDS).

Siehe auch *Hossa* "*Interjektion*", ohne Kommentar, *Hussa*" Ruf zum Antreiben, Hetzen, besonders bei der Jagd" (DWDS), ebenso italienisch *br* "Schallwort für das Aufjagen des Wildes" (REW # [1250](https://archive.org/details/romanischesetymo00meyeuoft/page/89/mode/1up)) und ähnliches mehr, etwa spanisch *arriba, arribar*, doch andererseits *Husar* "light-cavalry", "freebooter", *kursar* "pirate" zu lat. *currere* "to run", (etymonline: *hussar*), ebenso *Barbar*.

Die Semitische Etymologie, *das Wort G-ttes*, bleibt unterdessen wegen außen vor wegen assymetrischer Quellenlage. Siehe nur *piru* "Elefant", *al fil* "Elefant, (Schach) Läufer", *Behemot* (בְּהֵמָה‎ bəhēmā 'beast, cattle'—specifically, a plural of excellence *senus latu*), alle ungeklärte Metaphern.

---

3. Für kindliches Gebaren, Mantafahrer-Witze und sonstige Sondersprachen ist das althergebrachte Schriftum—*inter barbarum blabla silent legis*—regelmäßig nicht belastbar und von daher mit keinen Beweis *argumentum ab silencio* zu rechnen. Zumindest ist eine Hebräische Ableitung im 15 Jh. zu spät und müsste weitaus früher eingesetzt haben. *Boah ey* sowie *bor, por* könnten dafür nützliche Indizien sein.

@ChristianGeiselmann seine Boa, *Mit lat.* boa, *einem Wort unbekannter Herkunft (wahrscheinlich Lehnwort)* bei Pliny (DWDS/Pfeifer) ist als Riesenschlange gar ein sinnvoller Vergleich in den bereits angesprochenen Bedeutungen, angenommen die Semantik "hoch" lebte in Frankfurt fort, ferner im Sinne von Größe überhaupt, ohne dass die Worte ursächlich verwandt sein müssten.

Lautmalerisch außerdem *puh, pusten* wie lateinisch *spiro* usw.