# Warum ist das Mal in "ein paar Mal" Singular?

Tags: idiom, grammatical-number

Ich habe mich schon *[ein paar Mal](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Mal_Zeitpunkt)* gefragt, warum das "Mal" hier im Singular stehen muss.

Denn:

- wir kennen den Plural: *wenige Male*, *mehrere Male*
- zu "[paar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1197/wie-viele-sind-ein-paar)" steht sonst immer Plural: *ein paar Stunden*, *ein paar Kinder*

Gibt es eine Erklärung für diese eigenartige Ausnahme?

Comment: So eine Ausnahme ist das gar nicht, mir ist schon zwei Male oder drei Male Ähnliches begegnet.

Comment: Wir sagen auch "zwei Mal und "drei Mal", hier auch nicht in Plural. Dies könnte vielleicht den Ausdrück kontaminiert haben?

Comment: Ich werfe mal »Ich hab nur *ein paar Glas Wein* getrunken« in die Runde, weil ich glaube, dass das damit zu tun hat.

Comment: Bei *paar* steht nicht grundsätzlich Plural, vgl. "Ich trank ein paar Glas Wasser" und "Ich kaufte ein paar Kio Brot"

Comment: Genauso wie man gelegentlich [*ein paar Glas*](https://www.google.de/#tbm=bks&q=%22ein+paar+Glas%22) finden kann, gibt es auch [*ein paar Male*](https://www.google.de/?ion=1&espv=2&client=ubuntu#q=%22ein+paar+Male%22&tbm=bks&start=130), aber beides scheint mir eher die Ausnahme als die Regel.

Comment: imho ist das einfach Sprachfaulheit gepaart mit Ausnahmen. Da, wie ja schon festgestellt wurde, Mal sowohl zählbar als auch unzählbar vorkommt, ist es in zählbaren Fällen/Malen auch in unzählbarer Form benutzbar und der Faulheit wegen einfacher (eine Silbe gespart). Ich denke, das auch die "mathematische" Nutzung aus der Multiplikation reinspielt.     *5 mal 4 (5x4)*, *Das ist mir heute schon 3x passiert.*

Comment: Gleiches Phänomen mit "ein paar Euro(s)". Und es gibt auch das Wort "paarmal".

Comment: @Em1: interessanterweise schreibt Duden bei den Synonymen zu [paarmal](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/paarmal) *ein paar Male*

Comment: Ja, das habe ich auch gesehen, aber es heißt dort auch "(bei besonderer Betonung) paar Mal". — Ich hab grad auch mal im Grimm nachgeschaut. Wir können hier zeitlich sehr weit zurück gehen. Dort findet man Sachen wie: "im plural ist mal nur seltner noch flectiert", "gewöhnlich unflectiert". Und was ist eigentlich mit "für ein und allemal". "Alle" ist doch nun wirklich äußerst Plural. Und ganz nebenbei hat mich die Suche jetzt an eine Frage von mir erinnert. "damal/damals", "nochmal/nochmals". Das Mal hat es faustdick hinter den Ohren.

Comment: @Em1, nein, *je-* alterniert mit *e-* (jetzt, etzala), also dürfte das wohl *all-emal* sein. Ich bezweifle außerdem, dass die gesamte Bansbreite, in der *mal* aufschlägt, allein vom Begriff der Mahlzeit kommt. Schließlich muss es richtig heißen *ihr könnt mich allema*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Das Thema dreht sich um **Maß- und Mengenangaben**. Um canoonet zu zitieren:

> Männliche und sächliche Maß-, Mengen- und Münzbezeichnungen werden im Nominativ Singular gebraucht, wenn sie hinter einer Zahlenangabe stehen:
>
> *drei **Dutzend** Eier*
>
> *2,5 **Kilo** Äpfel*

Nicht anders verhält es sich mit *Malen*. Nun kennen wir aber den Fall, dass wir doch den Plural benutzen. Cannoonet sagt:

> Wenn der volle Begriff gemeint ist, d.h wenn mehrere einzelne Einheiten bezeichnet werden sollen, kann auch der Plural stehen:
>
> *Er trank drei große **Gläser** Bier.*
>
> *Es stehen fünf **Fässer** Bier vor der Tür.*

Sagt man also *mehrere Male* usw., werden die einzelnen Male dadurch hervorgehoben. Hinzu kommt, dass es auch sprachliche Gewohnheiten und Traditionen gibt, die sich nicht logisch erklären lassen und die dazu führen, dass man zwar *eine wenige Fuß dicke Mauer* hat, aber sie nur *wenige Male* gesehen hat.

===

Nun zu deinen Fragen bzgl. *ein paar Stunden* und *ein paar Kinder*. Dass *Kinder* keine Maßangabe sind, dürfte klar sein; die *Stunde* ist weiblich und deswegen steht sie im Plural (siehe Zitat 1). Hier könnte argumentiert werden, dass es bei "*ein paar Tage*" anders sein müsste - ja, anscheinend werden Zeitangaben grammatikalisch nicht als Mengenangaben behandelt - und *Mal* ist keine Zeitangabe (man sagt nicht, wie lange denn nun ein Mal dauert)!

Um die Verwirrung perfekt zu machen, kommt *mal* auch als Adverb und als Partikel vor. Daraus resultieren Wortkombinationen wie *einmal*, *allemal* etc. Die Faustregel, dass eine Zusammenschreibung die Bedeutung der einzelnen Wörter ins Metaphorische verschiebt, greift auch hier: *alle Male* ist nicht gleich *allemal* und *ein Mal* bedeutet etwas anderes als *einmal*.

Answer (score 1):

Als Ergänzung zur Antwort von Barth Zalewski: In einigen Sprachen, beispielsweise im Chinesischen oder Thai, werden sogenannte [Zählwörter](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z%C3%A4hlwort) verwendet. Dabei wird das Wort für die Zahl durch einen Ausdruck ergänzt, der beschreibt, *was* gezählt wird. Die Zahl und das Zählwort zusammen ergeben dann ein gemeinsames Wort, das sogenannte Zahlwort. Wenn man das Prinzip im Deutschen anwendet, hieße "zwei Bücher" etwa "zweibuch".

Im Japanischen (das viele Zählwörter aus dem Chinesischen übernommen hat) heißt "eine Person" beispielsweise 一人. Das ist ein Wort, gebildet aus den Zeichen für "eins" und "Person". "Ein Haus" heißt 一戸, und so weiter. Es gibt einen ganzen Schwung solcher Zählwörter, für spezifische Dinge wie Bankkonten, aber auch allgemein für "dünner, flacher Gegenstand" wie ein Stück Papier.

Im heutigen Deutsch sind solche Zählwörter nicht obligatorisch, aber gelegentlich findet man noch "Überbleibsel" davon. Man kann beispielsweise "zwei Glas Wasser" sagen statt "zwei Gläser Wasser". Dabei dient "Glas" als Zählwort, auch wenn es nicht mit der Zahl zu einem Wort zusammengezogen wird. Andere Beispiele sind "zwei Laib Brot", "zwei Sack Kartoffeln" oder "zwei Stück Vieh". Ich würde "ein paar Mal" auch als ein solches übriggebliebenes Zählwort einordnen.

Answer (score 0):

Beim Beispiel in der Frage (Ich habe mich schon ein *paar Mal* gefragt, warum das "Mal" hier im Singular stehen muss.) handelt es sich um ein Adverb.

Laut [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/paarmal) ist *paarmal* ein Adverb, das bei besonderer Betonung auch als *paar Mal* geschrieben werden kann, wobei letzteres die weiter verbreitete Schreibweise ist.

Answer (score 0):

Ich glaube es ist so aus historischen Gründen. Ich habe die historische Entwicklung von "ein paar Mal" gefunden. In der Vergangenheit was es "ein paar Male" oder "ein paarmal".

Alte Orthographie

> ein paarmal, aber ein paar Male

Neuregelung 1996

> ein paar Mal(e)

Duden 2000

> ein paarmal, auch ein paarmal, auch ein paar Mal (bei besonderer Betonung)

Deutsche Akademi

> ein paarmal/ein paar Mal

Comment: Richtig. "-mal" ist ein Adverbsuffix. Erst die Neuregelung der Rechtschreibung hat das Suffix substantiviert.

Comment: Die Historie ist lediglich die zeitliche Dokumentation einer Praxis. Eine Erklärung ist es nicht. Zu jeder Frage, wieso etwas so und so ist, kann man behaupten, das sei aus historischen Gründen so. Ohne je falsch zu sein erklärt es genau gar nichts.

Comment: @userunknown Ich kann dir nicht zustimmen. Die verwurzelte Sprachen wie Deutsch, Englisch, Arabisch, Türkisch, Spanisch, Chinesisch haben viele unerklärbaren Regeln, weil diese Sprachen sehr natürlich gewachsen sind. In meiner Antwort wollte ich zeigen, dass *ein paar Mal* nicht Singular so wie jetzt war. Viele Regeln (sogar Ausnahmen) sind wie die Sprachen natürlich gewachsen. Hast du schon mal Flüsterpost gespielt?